# Can I include year as an independent variable in this nested logistic regression design?

Tags: r, regression, multinomial-distribution

I want to make a nested logistic regression in R with the package [mlogit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/index.html).

I would like to test how producer's decision to enter organisations (14 organisations) or not is affected by different factors.

Producer can be in specific organisation and other according to year. I was advised to use year as separate variables in columns. This is OK. But for my different organizations will it be the same? So if my producer appear in my database several times (6 times) in row, isn't it redundant?

Have you an Idea of the struture of database that I can adopt?

Here is how my data looks like in R:

```
   Year   Organisation   Member AGE.Member ...
1  2005 Organisation 1 Member 1         37
2  2005 Organisation 1 Member 2         32
3  2005 Organisation 3 Member 3         32
4  2005 Organisation 4 Member 4         35
5  2005 Organisation 2 Member 5         33
6  2005 Organisation 3 Member 6         33

'data.frame':   18 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ ANNEE       : int  2005 2005 2005 2005 2005 2005 2005 2005 2005 2006 2006 2006...
     $ Organisation: Factor w/ 4 levels "Organisation 1",..: 1 1 3 4 2 3 2 3 3 2 ...
 $ Member      : Factor w/ 9 levels "Member 1","Member 2",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 ...
     $ AGE.Member  : int  37 32 32 35 33 33 32 32 33 37 ...
```

Comment: What's your dependent variable in this data?

Comment: it is the choice of organisation which can explain by age.....

Comment: I mean, in the table that you showed us, which of those variables is your dependent variable? Organization?

Comment: exactly it is the choice of organization